# PHP - sometimes timeouts while accessing Magento via SOAP

Tags: soap, timeout, command-line-interface

I've got a simple script which should:
1. Get all customers from Magento (into an array)
2. Get their full addresses (iterate through the array with a foreach)
2a. sleep for 3 sec
3. Get their order history (same foreach)
3a. sleep once more for 3 sec

I'm doing this from the command line with PHP CLI.
The script runs for a couple of minutes - sometimes even half an hour but most often the script sees an error and can't fully iterate through all data:

> ```
>     PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /var/www/soap/mag_crm.php:162
> Stack trace:
> #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://myurl...', 'urn:Mage_Api_Mo...', 1, 0)
> #1 /var/www/soap/mag_crm.php(162): SoapClient->__call('salesOrderList', Array)
> #2 /var/www/soap/mag_crm.php(162): SoapClient->salesOrderList('fd66fc18e4b8...', Array)
> #3 /var/www/soap/mag_crm.php(85): fetchAllOrders(259)
> #4 {main}
>   thrown in /var/www/soap/mag_crm.php on line 162
> ```

How could I improve this script or in case of an error like this - just retry or so?

The code itself is easy - just plain function calls like that for instance:

```
$aOrders = fetchAllOrders ( $oCustomer->customer_id );
```

(within the foreach)

Comment: I've got this problem now with a script that fetches images. With this script I need to press on F5 at least 3 - 7 times and then I might be lucky.
I got:
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in ...
but only if I get a .. is it a timeout if it happens sometimes after five seconds, sometimes after 30 seconds?

Comment: Unfortuanately I can't figure out where this problem comes from.
The website is loading for one or two minutes and then it runs into the error. Does anybody have a hint for me what I could do?
Maybe I need to output something from within the loop and/or pause the loop to avoid CPU peaks? If it would be a timeout, it should say so, right?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your magento settings to :

```
System -> Index Management
Check All Items
Change Action to "Change Index Mode"
Select "Manual"
Save
```

The problem is that the site tries to refresh the picture all the time and kill the session.